# How to get the class of a class property in php

Tags: php, class

I was experimenting with php, trying to get the class of a class property.

```
class A{
    public $a;
}

class B extends A{
    public $b;
}

class C extends B{
    public $c;
}

$c = new C();

echo get_class($c); // C

echo get_class($c->a);  // false
echo get_class($c->b);  // false
echo get_class($c->c);  // false
```

Using the `get_class` method I can get "C" from *$c*,
 but with the properties *$c->a*, *$c->b*, *$c->c* that function returns "false".

---

**Question**

How can I get the class the properties belong to? ..like:

```
echo foo($c->a);  // A
echo foo($c->b);  // B
echo foo($c->c);  // C
```

is it possible?

Comment: @PaulCrovella yes! it does what I was trying to achieve, thank you

Answer (score 1):

`get_class() to get current class name` and `get_parent_class() to get parent or extended class`

```
echo get_class($c);
$b = get_parent_class($c);//this will get extended class B
echo $b;
echo get_parent_class(new $b());//$b="B" then we call new B class to get parent class 'A'
```